# Skybox in Scene view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have browsed for the problem and made sure that I was not missing out on some toggle button.

1. I have `Effects` button toggled.
2. Also,the little sun button is toggled.
3. I have applied material to Skybox i.e `Edit`--> `Render setting` -->`Skybox material`

Yet I do not see the skybox graphics in sceen view. All I see is the wireframe for skybox.
Though I can see the skybox in Game View.
Here is how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

What might be the problem here, please?

Comment: The SkyBox is relative to the camera and the scene view is independent of the camera which means you cannot see it. Why do you need to see it?

Comment: Have the feeling you just don't have the effect enabled [see image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gCKSe.png) Also which version of unity are you using? as older versions might differentiate from this. ( 4.6)

Comment: I am using Unity 4.5 and I made sure I have this effect enabled :)

Comment: @Catwood: I wanted to project a direction light on the sun so as to have a flare effect which would not be possible without having skybox gaphics in Scene view.

Comment: @Catwood: Oh, it is not really that way. We surely can have a skybox in Scene view.

Comment: @Simran Okay, i am wrong. Check [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/41532/enable-skybox-in-the-scene-view.html)

Comment: @Catwood: I had checked that before asking here. and in the snapshot, you can check, the button is toggled yet no skybox graphics in scene view.

Comment: @Simran I notice you have two cameras in the scene, maybe this has had an effect. Just a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: I am actually following some tuts and they have two cameras too but they clearly have Skybox in Scene view. :/